# jupyter lab 2.2.2 %pylab inline deprecation warnings

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

After upgrading `matplotlib` and `jupyter`, `jupyter lab`, the inline magic produces deprecation warnings. While this is somewhat helpful, these warnings get in the way.

Of course one can turn off the warnings:
`import warnings warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')`
But it doesn't seem to be the best way.

Question: how to resolve these warnings without turning all warnings off?

The magic:

`%pylab inline`

Warnings:

```
In C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\_classic_test.mplstyle: 
The text.latex.preview rcparam was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.3 and will be removed two minor releases later.
In C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\_classic_test.mplstyle: 
The mathtext.fallback_to_cm rcparam was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.3 and will be removed two minor releases later.
In C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\_classic_test.mplstyle: Support for setting the 'mathtext.fallback_to_cm' rcParam is deprecated since 3.3 and will be removed two minor releases later; use 'mathtext.fallback : 'cm' instead.
In C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\_classic_test.mplstyle: 
The validate_bool_maybe_none function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.3 and will be removed two minor releases later.
In C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\_classic_test.mplstyle: 
The savefig.jpeg_quality rcparam was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.3 and will be removed two minor releases later.
In C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\_classic_test.mplstyle: 
The keymap.all_axes rcparam was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.3 and will be removed two minor releases later.
In C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\_classic_test.mplstyle: 
The animation.avconv_path rcparam was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.3 and will be removed two minor releases later.
In C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\_classic_test.mplstyle: 
The animation.avconv_args rcparam was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.3 and will be removed two minor releases later.
```

Comment: `_classic_test.mplstyle` is used for testing, see [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/16700#issuecomment-604406285). I guess you can simply delete it.

Comment: After deleting it the warnings go away. Still, this seems to be a work-around. I tried to uninstall `matplotlib` as in the github issue, this does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pylab is deprecated, as far I'm aware. See the link below (best I could find, a thread on Ipython repo). I think there were many issues with it clobbering namespaces. The typical recommendation I've seen is simply to replace it with the `%matplotlib inline`.

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5071/#issuecomment-34547616